# Is there a way I can restrict my phone to connect to network I set only?

Tags: wi-fi

I want my android phone to connect to my office WIFI only or the WIFI that I choose.
If I try to connect to any other WIFI by entering password it should not connect.

Is there a way to do this. I am a programmer as well so If someone can share any idea about a custom APP to perform this task, that would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while the community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, please use [so].

Comment: Why do you want to do this?